# How understand scatter like this way?

Tags: dataset, visualization

I am trying to learn some EDA skills and I get a scatter like this way:
[image]

I don't see that there are some model relationships or group-related patterns between these two data. I mean what I thought was right? I am not pretty sure about it.

If not mind, could anyone help me and give me some advice on multivariate plotting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, your data shows that for a given value of $x$, you can have a wide range of $y$ values and that the ranges depend on the value of $x$.

This usually happens when you have a partial view of the global picture, meaning that there are other variables in your data that could help explain the relationship.

To leverage your plots, you can consider changing the color of the markers depending on an additional variable. You could also change the size of the marker depending on another one. There are a couple of options there, depending on what you look for.

EDA is usually not the final step per se, you may rather ask yourself some questions related to the problem you are trying to solve, and see if the data accounts for it.

Does this help?

Comment: great answer, just to add a clarification about your answer:
**To leverage your plots, you can consider changing the color of the markers depending on an additional variable.**
this can be done using [seaborn's scatterplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) with the help of parameter `hue`, this parameter should be passed a _categorical_ (discrete) variable from you dataset, in this case, points will be grouped with different colors (with respect to values of the passed _categorical_ variable).